# optimize matrix of variables in R

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

I have a square matrix of values, `Q`, and a same-sized diagonal matrix of variables, `W`, and I want to take `exp(W*Q)` (where here `*` is matrix multiplication of course). This effectively scales the `i`th row in `Q` by the `[i,i]` element of `W`. My objective function will be to minimize `(c-exp(W*Q)[y,z])^2`, where `c` is some constant I have and `[y,z]` just says I'm choosing the `[y,z]` element of the matrix, where I am choosing a particular `y` and `z`.

I'm trying to use the `optim()` function in R, but to do so I need to create the diagonal matrix of variables `W`. Is it possible to do this in R? Or alternatively, is there another function I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at the `diag` function

Comment: Thank you. But I would need to create a diagonal matrix of variables that will then be optimized over...do you know if that's possible in R?

Comment: Yes, `optim` will optimise a vector, and you can just convert the vector to a diagonal matrix using `diag` in your optimisation formula - e.g. `(c-exp(diag(W)*Q)[y,z])^2`.

Comment: ok, I think that worked. Thank you so much!